# Plot Legends and Frame Ticks in Array Plots

Tags: graphics, image, legending, list-manipulation

Why do the frame ticks go away when PlotLegends->Automatic is inserted in an Array Plot?  For instance, the following code produces an Array Plot with Frame Ticks.

```
ArrayPlot[Table[Random[], {i, 10}, {j, 10}], MaxPlotPoints -> 1000, 
ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
PlotLabel -> Style["Array Plot of Raw Data", 11, Bold, Black],
PlotRangePadding -> 0., ImageSize -> Full, 
AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> True, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
FrameLabel -> {Style["Y", 11, Bold, Black], 
Style["X", 11, Bold, Black]}, 
FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 11, Bold]]
```

Then when I add PlotLegends->Automatic, they go away!

```
ArrayPlot[Table[Random[], {i, 10}, {j, 10}], MaxPlotPoints -> 1000, 
ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
PlotLabel -> Style["Array Plot of Raw Data", 11, Bold, Black], 
PlotRangePadding -> 0., ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
FrameLabel -> {Style["Y", 11, Bold, Black], 
Style["X", 11, Bold, Black]}, 
FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 11, Bold], 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Here is the really strange thing about this.  When I go to "drag" the array plot graphic as if I were going to move it somewhere or manipulate it, the Frame Ticks suddenly appear!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `ImageSize->Full` option. Try leaving it out or specify your `ImageSize` to a certain size (e.g. `500`) instead of `Full`.

```
otherOptions = {MaxPlotPoints -> 1000, 
   ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Array Plot of Raw Data", 11, Bold, Black], 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0., ImageSize -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
   Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Y", 11, Bold, Black], 
     Style["X", 11, Bold, Black]}};

Column[Table[
  ArrayPlot[Table[Random[], {i, 10}, {j, 10}], 
   FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {All, None}}, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black, 11, Bold], 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, otherOptions[[i]]], {i, 1, 
   Length[otherOptions], 1}]]
(* the problem shows up in the 5th plot down, which is your ImageSize option *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why it affects the frame ticks?